# Google Maps: Passing extra arguments into GeoCoder for InfoWindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, scope

This is my first post. I'm completely stuck and could use some help with adding infoWindows to Google Maps. The data I'm actually going to use (NOT the API I used here) doesn't have lat/lon and has multiple values.

Things are fine until `infoWindow`, but I can't pass any other arguments into the `geocoder` callback. Thanks in advance for the help!

Credit goes to Minghui Yu: http://goo.gl/zvAKZ8. Mine uses different data for the infowindow and will have probably about 30 markers.

Here's the relevant code [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/secondbreakfast/yNXdF/2):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;
var i;
var mapData;
var locations = [];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk',
        async: false,
        success: function (mapData) {
        locations.push(mapData.name);
    }

});
    initialize();
});

function initialize() {
    setMarkers(map, locations);
}

function setMarkers(map, address) {
    for (var i = 0; i < address.length; i++) {
        setMarker(map, address[i])
    }
}

function setMarker(map, address) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    },

    function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,
                "click", function () {

                    //HAVING THE PROBLEM HERE. Not sure how to separate this from the callback. 
                  infowindow.setContent(mapData.main.temp);
                    // But this works if you run it:
                //infowindow.setContent(address);

                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declare myData as a global variable.

But here you have `mapData` as parameter of ajax success callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk',
        async: false,
        success: function (mapData) {  //locally scoped which can't override
        locations.push(mapData.name);                
        }
});
```

This will not override the global variable.

Instead do like this

```
var gmapData = {};
```

and use it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk',
        async: false,
        success: function (mapData) {
        locations.push(mapData.name);            
        gmapData = mapData; //assign mapData to global variable
        }
});
```

Now use in `infoWindow`

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {   
            //infowindow.setContent() will accept only string 
            //whereas temp is numeric, so convert to string                 
        infowindow.setContent(gmapData.main.temp.toString());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/yNXdF/4/)